# babel config not working in project as npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Created an npm package with the following `babel.config.json` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"
  ]
}
```

And when importing this package in another project, i get following error:

```
experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you compiled the package and are importing the output of the compilation process or are you importing the sources? Looks like the latter.

Comment: i think not. how can i do it? i thought that by configuring babel it will happened auto with webpack or something in the other project?? @fast-reflexes

Comment: Are you using Webpack or Babel? Seems like you're using Babel, then you have to run the `babel` command, then add a `package.json` to the output folder (with package directives if necessary) THEN you can import it as a package.

Comment: yes babel. what do you mean add package.json to the output folder? there is a package.json file in the root dir ..

Comment: Yes in the root of the project but not in the root of the output folder. Only the output folder is the package you import, you don't import the sources, only the compiled output. The `package.json` in the output may indicate what kind of a package it is, its entrypoint and more: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json

Comment: so i build the project with babel then what do i publish to npm? what is the output folder? becuase to git i push the original folder..

Comment: Output folder is the folder where the output of your compilation goes. You can publish to npm or jfrog or some other npm registry, or just link it locally if you only want to use the project yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

1. An npm package needs to be compiled / transpiled before it can be used as an npm package. Why? Because both jsx and Typescript requires build tools to be converted into runnable code in NodeJS and an npm package should come without assumptions on such tools. Use Babel or `tsc` to transpile your source files into an output folder `out` in your project. You can also use Webpack to transpile and bundle your package even though typically, the sources are not bundled in a package because it hampers the possibilities to tree-shake.

   Pay attention to whether you want the npm package to offer esm (ES, es6) or cjs (CommonJS) modules and whether you want to include types or not. cjs is the more traditional approach whereas esm is newer. Use cjs to begin with if you don't know what you're doing so far since esm can be trickier to consume. You can also supply both of these variants in your package.

   Read about this process in the documentation of Babel, `tsc` and Webpack but you WILL have to run the `babel`, `tsc` or `webpack` commands to get the transpiled file(s).

   **EDIT**: It might be possible to keep jsx and Typescript in an npm package but it is absolutely not how it is usually done. For example, with `ts-loader` (often used to process Typescript files in Webpack) there is the setting [`allowTsInNodeModules`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader). It seems however that it would require quite a lot of more configuration and it's unclear what advantage this strategy has.
2. Add a `package.json` to the `out` folder. Usually we use `package.json` in a project to determine what to download for our project and so on but at the root of an npm package there should also be a `package.json`. This file determines what dependencies your package has but also what kind of package it is, its entrypoint, whether it has types and much more: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json
3. You now have an npm package in the `out` folder. Either publish it to an npm registry (the most common and the default being `npmjs.org` but others, private and public exist too) OR hot-link it locally to another project with npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link

You have now taken your first steps in package building. It's a big and quite complicated subject once you get into different kind of modules and tree-shaking and npm inner workings, so be patient and take one thing at a time.

PS! The `out` folder can be named something else as well ;) DS